# when use smtplib to send email show error Permission denied

Tags: python, python-2.7, gmail

```
def send_email(self):
    try:
        s = smtplib.SMTP(config.smtp_server, 587)
        logging.info("hello world")
        s.set_debuglevel(1)
        s.ehlo()
        logging.info("hello world2")
        s.starttls()
        logging.info("hello world3")
        s.ehlo()
        s.login(config.str_gmail_user, config.str_gmail_pwd)
        s.sendmail(config.email_from,self.email_to , self.msg.as_string())
        s.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info("erro")
        logging.info('e: {}'.format(e))
        raise e
```

I am try to write send_email function using python smtplib , but it face error

the log as below :

INFO     2017-06-29 18:05:37,815 send_email.py:18] hello world2
send: 'STARTTLS\r\n'

reply: '220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS\r\n'

reply: retcode (220); Msg: 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS

INFO     2017-06-29 18:05:37,978 send_email.py:26] erro

INFO     2017-06-29 18:05:37,978 send_email.py:27] e: [Errno 13] Permission denied

INFO     2017-06-29 18:05:37,979 user.py:91] e: [Errno 13] Permission denied

config.smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"

it seems fail when running s.starttls()

Any ideas about this? thanks for helping

Comment: Try using `s.starttls()` after the  login.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to format you answer and make it more legible so that others can understand and help you more easily.